# How can I provide resource-based policy in my lambda via serverles.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless.yml to deploy lambdas to AWS and I'd like to know how to configure the resource-based policy for my lambda.

I deploy a customised alias to my lambda and need to grant `invoke:lambda` in the policy of the resouce-based policy. So when you open lambda -> configuration -> permission, the policy should appear as below

[image]

when I use the `role` configure in serverless.yml, it only changes the permission for my lambda execution role. How can I modify the `Resource-based policy` for my lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used before the API Gateway Resource Policy:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#resource-policy

For the lambda function association directly you can take a look at that thread:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4926

Comment: How can I specify it to a `alias` of my lambda function?

Comment: There is a plugin for that `serverless-aws-alias`.
This article helped me on that:
https://medium.com/swlh/serverless-alias-insight-e1db93a69562

Answer (score 0):

An example serverless.yaml would look like this:

```
  provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    memorySize: 128
    stage: dev
    apiGateway: 
      resourcePolicy:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action: execute-api:Invoke
          Resource:
            - execute-api:/*/*/*
          Condition:
            IpAddress:
              aws:SourceIp:
                - 'your ip here'
```

[How to restrict access to a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295034/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-lambda/69991106#69991106)

Please note that the resource policy currently only works for the **REST** API Gateways. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html

HTTP APIs do not support resource policies.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30357368)